# nesting design in divs

Tags: html, css, web

please excuse me as my competence with web programming is pretty limited, which makes even googling for the topics difficult, since I don't know the correct terms..

Anyways my question, (which I'm sure will be worded oddly, seeing as I dont really know how to talk about this) is:

Is there any way to achieve this pseduocode with html + css?

css file:

```
#ropeimage {
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background:url(images/rope.png);
}

#ropetext {
    <div id="ropeimage">
   /* some text properties */
}
```

and then in the html file

```
<div id="ropetext">hello</div>
<div id="ropetext">there</div>
```

the reason i ask is, even though i know i can do something akin to

```
<div id="ropetext"><div id="ropeimage">hello</div></div>
<div id="ropetext"><div id="ropeimage">there</div></div>
```

if i know i always need this, why not have it tucked away in the css file.

If anyone is curious, what I'm trying to do is build a div that will repeat-x a 'rope' image,then vertically print some text. I cant have all this normally in one div, because the background image of the rope would repeat under the text, so i need two divs so that the image stops repeating as soon as it hits the text div.

[a crude picture explaining what im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q48NA.png)

Answer (score 2):

I believe rather than using `id` you want to use `class`.

So your CSS would look like so:

```
.ropetext {
    /* properties */
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div class="ropetext"></div>
```

The difference between a class and an ID is that you want to use an ID for only one HTML tag.  A class can apply to many tags.

Furthermore, you can make nested style definitions in your CSS:

```
.rope {
    /* properties defining any rope div in general */
    position: relative;
}

.rope .top {
    /* properties defining the top of the div */
    /* background image stuff goes here */
}

.rope .bottom {
    /* properties defining the bottom of the div */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<div class="rope">
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't tested this but I believe this is on track to what you're looking for.

Comment: I think we both misunderstood what he wants to do....cuz if you look closer at his code, he seems to just want to repeat that image....which is not what we are both suggesting

Comment: he needs a large box, with a repeated image, interupted by a smaller div with text, he just repeats that image manually instead of in a flexible container

Comment: I essentially want to nest divs within the css, so that i could call one div in the html, giving me the same effect of nesting divs in the html. for organizational purposes

Comment: theres a way easier way though...I'll let someone else answer though, and you can't nest divs inside divs in css

Comment: Just noticing your comments now...  I think he/she does want to use classes instead of IDs anyway.

Comment: yes true, but it will be one id with a repeating background, and a text class or something along those lines, notice he wasnt closing those divs, he just wants to repeat them, but doen'st know html/css too well

Comment: sorry about this, please take another look at the question, the repeating/not closing divs was a typo

Comment: the latest edit is exactly what i'm looking for, but as i stated, even though i understand you can do this, is there any 'neater' way to do it, since everytime I will say `<div class="rope">` i would need the properties of `top` so why not have all that in the css, instead of repeating code in the html

Comment: I don't think there is a neater way if you want the background to repeat only in `top` and not in `bottom`.  If you want `top` and `bottom` associated with one another, I think this is the only way.